# Error al intentar leer WSGI handler en IIS con DJANGO

Tags: python, django, iis

Etoy levantando una aplicación de Django con IIS en Windows 10; sin embargo me muestra el siguiente error.

Me guié con el siguiente video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgTFrAwXeoI

Error occurred while reading WSGI handler: Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aplicacion\wfastcgi.py", line 711, in main env, 
handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path) File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aplicacion\wfastcgi.py", line 568, in read_wsgi_handler return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name) File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aplicacion\wfastcgi.py", line 551, in get_wsgi_handler raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported' % handler_name) ValueError:"django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()" could not be imported StdOut: StdErr:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Netza. Por favor, pon el mensaje de error en formato de texto y no en imagen. Asi será más legible. Indicanos tambien que intentas hacer para que saliera dicho error. que has investigado al respecto ? Has debugueado o puesto logs? Un saludo

Comment: Hola Lois. Listo!!